# mysql - very complex query involving multiple left joins and

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

MySQL:
The BIG food-box has several parallel lines of **100 inches.** Position in the food-box is very important so it's important to keep track of inches.

**Each compartment of the food-box is decided to be 4 inches so 25 compartments total.**

User can fill up each line in one-to-one relation meaning one user per line.

`UserCompartments: (UserId, PositionStart, PositionEnd)`  -> (9, 52, 100), (8, 44, 77).

Each compartment has several lines too and user requires help from several servers in parallel and therefore no need to check if a server is overlapping another.

`Servers: (ServerId, ServerPositionStart, ServerPositionEnd, LineId, UserId)`   -> (7, 55, 98, 4, 9), (8, 53, 77, 9). The range in this table will always be a subset of the corresponding range of User table .

`ServerBooking: (CompartmentId, ServerId, UserId) ->  (4, 7, 9)`  CompartmentId will be from 1-25 only because there are total of 25 boxes.

Some servers maybe unavailable for certain inch position.

```
ServerTemporaryOutage: (ServerId, ContainerId)
```

Some servers maybe available beyond their regular availability.

```
ServerTemporaryAvailability (ServerId, PositionStart, PositionEnd)
```

Now I want to fetch results in terms of compartments and not inches to let user see it and decide which server to assign to which un-booked compartments but the issue is

1) Everything is in inches (Except ServerBooking and ServerTemporaryOutage) while I want the result in terms of containerid and just division will not cut it because it's all very position-sensitive.

2) I need to fetch temporary outage and temporary availability on top of booking to let user see which server is doing exactly what. I know some kind of left join will be in there but obviously this makes no sense:

```
Select ?? from Server 
join UserCompoartments u on s.userid = ...
left join serverbooking sb on  sb on sb.serverid = s.serverid and sb.userid = s.userid
left join servertemporaryoutage so on so.serverid = s.serverid
left join servertemporaryavailibility sa on sa.serverid = s.serverid
```

This will not give me what I want:

```
CompartmentId (1...25), Server-Statuses: Available, Booked, Overtime, Outage
```

The result should have 25 rows because there are 25 compartments.

Comment: What is ServerPositionStart and ServerPositionEnd?

Comment: What do you mean by 'inches' in ' in terms of compartments and not inches'?

Comment: @nikita2206 ServerPositionStart means starting position of inches the server can serve... for example, server 7 can only serve starting from 58 inches onwards and will stop at 98 inches.

Comment: @nikita2206 What I meant was I want the result to look like this: CompartmentId (1...25), Server-Status: Available/Booked/Overtime/Outage   <-- you see how this has no mention of inches? Only compartment. ...Compartmentment with CompartmentId 1 would start from 1 to stop on 4 inches and so on.